# Each Java Future Controls a Core for Its Lifetime

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java, future

I am developing a Load Test application in Java for an Ethereum blockchain, using the web3j library. The specific functions used from this library, send transactions asynchronously, and return Future objects. That library provides many features which met all my needs initially for the application development. However, after designing and re-designing a load test application, I noticed an issue. I can only have N Futures deployed at once, where N is the number of available cores on my machine.

This is very inefficient since each transaction takes at least 10 seconds to integrate into the blockchain, and the Futures are continuously running in the background. If they are converted to RxJava observables (using the from() function of RxJava), will they still continuously run in the background to check if their data is available, or would I be able to overlay many checks at once. For example, if a check took 0.1 seconds and I needed each future to be checked once a second, then I could run 10 checks on one core instead of 1. If converting a Future to Observable will still exhibit the continuous-core-usage behavior, is there a different way to go about this that doesn't involve refactoring a lot of the web3j internal code?

The culprit may be this function, contained within the [Async.java](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/web3j/utils/Async.java) file. This function is called by internal web3j functions to send Transactions.

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> run(Callable<T> callable) {
    CompletableFuture<T> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // we need to explicityly catch any exceptions,
        // otherwise they will be silently discarded
        try {
            result.complete(callable.call());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            result.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "I can only have N Futures deployed at once, where N is the number of available cores on my machine." - What exactly do you mean by that?  What exactly happens when you try to "deploy" the N+1th Future?  I think there's a misunderstanding somewhere that needs to be cleared up.

Comment: When I deploy the N+1th Future it doesn't execute until one of the currently executing Futures are finished.

Comment: We need to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that demonstrates this before we can be much help.  My gut says that this is to do with the number of threads in your `ExecutorService`, but without code we cannot give you proper advice.

Comment: This is called by web3j functions during transaction sending, it may be the culprit: public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> run(Callable<T> callable) {
        CompletableFuture<T> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            // we need to explicityly catch any exceptions,
            // otherwise they will be silently discarded
            try {
                result.complete(callable.call());
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                result.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

Comment: Please do not put code in a comment, as I cannot read that.  Please instead edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you expect your task to return a result, you should use `supplyAsync` rather than `runAsync`.

But onto the more substantive part of your question, when you call `runAsync` or `supplyAsync` with only the task to be run, it will run on the JVM-wide `ForkJoinPool`, which as you have guessed has as many threads available to it as has cores on your machine.  You can, however, also supply an `ExecutorService` of your choice, which may have more threads than cores.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_DESIRED_THREADS);

CompletableFuture<T> result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(callable, executor);
```

The above code will allow as many as `NUM_DESIRED_THREADS` tasks to run concurrently.